# Multiple Search URLS and Google Analytics

Tags: search, drupal, google-analytics

I'm wondering if anyone has any insight for capturing statistics for an embedded search box and button.  We have several website search urls we have programmed into a drop-down menu where a user selects which index they want to search.

Now, I'm needing to find out the number of searches that took place from our website.

I thought an easy way to determine the number of searches would be to capture the number of clicks on the button.  But I haven't been able to figure out if there is another way to capture that for the different search urls.

Another layer of complicity is, I'm using Drupal's customized search module for creating the search drop-down, box, and button.

Does anyone have any insight they could provide or resources I could check out?